# ReactJS - Alternative to passing useState between files

Tags: reactjs

#### Background

I have a file that presents my main page `Dash.js`

This presents some data from an API on a "card", from two other files `List.js` and `ListLoading.js`

I have an additional "card" which I can trigger open with default `useState` value of 1, and the `onClick` works to close, as you will see in the dash.js file.

#### Current Code

```js
    //Dash.js

function Dash(props) {

    //control additional card
    const [openCard, setopenCard] = React.useState(0);

    const closeCard = () => {
        setopenCard(0);
    }

    //set API repo
    const apiUrl = (`http://example.com/api/`);

    axios.get(apiUrl, {
    withCredentials: true }).then((res) =>{
      setAppState({ loading: false, repos: res.data.emails });
                    });



return (
    {(openCard>0 &&
        <Card>
            <Cardheader onClick={() => closeCard()}>
                Click here to close
            </Cardheader>
            <Cardbody>
                Some data here
            </Cardbody>
        </Card>
     )
    || null
    }

    <Card>
        <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} repost={appState.repos} />
    <Card>
);
}
```

```js
    //List.js

const List = (props) => {
  const { repos } = props;

  if (!repos || repos.length === 0) return <p>No data available</p>;
  for (var key in repos) {
    return (
   
      {repos.map((repo) => { 
        return (
            <p className='repo-text max-width' >ID:{repo.id}{" "}Value:{repo.value} </p>
        );}
      )}
  );}
};
export default List;
```

```js
    //ListLoading.js

function WithListLoading(Component) {
  return function WihLoadingComponent({ isLoading, ...props }) {
    if (!isLoading) return <Component {...props} />;
    return (
      <p style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '30px' }}>
        Fetching data may take some time, please wait
      </p>
    );
  };
}
export default WithListLoading;
```

#### Desired Outcome

I want to set the the value for `openCard.useState()` to the `repos.id`.
e.g. `onClick={() => openCard({repos.id})}`

The complication of this is that I need to retrieve that code from List.js and pass it to the useState for the openCard, which is in Dash.js.

I am still fairly new to react so this is proving a little tricky to work out how to do.

#### What I've tried

- I have looked into [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext), but either it has confused me or I am right to think this would not work for what I am trying to do.
- I have looked into redux, however this seems like that may be overkill for this solution.
- I have tried a series of passing the different constants via import/export however I now understand that useState is not designed to work this way and should really be used within the function/class where it is contained.

So any thoughts to remedy would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is List.js related to ListLoading? Is it just being wrapped with thee HOC WithListLoading to create ListLoading component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes I believe that's the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to restate what I understood your issue to be:

1. You have a parent component that renders a list of objects and can render a detail card of one of the object.
2. You want to have a single item in your list of objects be able to tell the parent "please open card 123".

Now to look at the options you considered:

**Redux** I agree Redux is overkill for this. Redux is usually only necessary if you need complex, possibly async reading and writing to a single shared datasource across the whole scope of your application. For a little UI interaction like this, it is *definitely* not worth setting up Redux.

**React Context** Context relies on a Provider component, which you wrap some chunk of your app in. Any component below that Provider can then use `useContext` to reach into the memory of that Provider. You can store anything in there that you could store in a component, from a single state variable up to a more complex `useReducer` setup. So, in a way, this basically does what you were hoping to do with static variables passing the state around. This is the right solution if you were going to be using this state value across a wide variety of components.

**Props** are probably the right way to go here - since you have a parent who wants to get messages from a child directly you can give the child a callback function. This is the same as the `onClick` function you can give a button, except here you can pass your list a `onShowCard` function.

In your Dash:

```js
<ListLoading
  isLoading={appState.loading} repost={appState.repos}
  onShowCard={(cardId) => setopenCard(cardId)} />
```

At the end of the List:

```js
{repos.map((repo) => { 
  return (
    <button key={repo.id} className='repo-text max-width' onClick={() => { props.onShowCard(repo.id) }>
      ID:{repo.id}{" "}Value:{repo.value}
    </button>
  );}
)}
```

Comment: thanks @Zack - should this be `onClick={() => props.onShowCard(repo.id) }` rather than `onClick={() => { props.onShowCard(repo.id) }` ?

Comment: Those are equivalent - when you have a single statement to evaluate in the function body of an arrow function, the wrapping braces can be omitted. I left them in to keep it clear that this was a function body, but you can safely remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass on the function to update state to ListLoading component which will be forwarded to List component assuming it is wrapped by thee HOC WithListLoading.

Inside `List` you can then attach and `onClick` on the element to pass on the id of the clicked element

```
function Dash(props) {

    //control additional card
    const [openCard, setopenCard] = React.useState(0);

    const closeCard = () => {
        setopenCard(0);
    }

    //set API repo
    const apiUrl = (`http://example.com/api/`);

       axios.get(apiUrl, {
           withCredentials: true 
       }).then((res) =>{
         setAppState({ loading: false, repos: res.data.emails });
       });

    const handleOpen = id => {
      setopenCard(id);
   }

    return (
        {(openCard>0 &&
            <Card>
                <Cardheader onClick={() => closeCard()}>
                    Click here to close
                </Cardheader>
                <Cardbody>
                    Some data here
                </Cardbody>
            </Card>
         )
        || null
        }
    
        <Card>
            <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} repost={appState.repos} handleOpen={handleOpen} />
        <Card>
    );
}

const List = (props) => {
  const { repos, handleOpen } = props;

  if (!repos || repos.length === 0) return <p>No data available</p>;
  for (var key in repos) {
    return (
   
      {repos.map((repo) => { 
        return (
            <p className='repo-text max-width' onClick={() => props.handleOpen(repo.id)} >ID:{repo.id}{" "}Value:{repo.value} </p>
        );}
      )}
  );}
};
export default List;
```